# Passing API Key, usr/pwd in httppost URL. is it permitted? txtwire API

Tags: java, web-services, rest, authentication, sms

I am trying to use txtwire (for sending SMS) and they provide a httppost service mentioned below. I know it is "https" but still.. is it OK to pass my API key, userName & Password in the URL?

There is no Basic Auth Mechanism because service expects everything in URL.

[https://api.txtwire.com/httppost?phone=18885554433,18885554422&username={username}&password={password}&api_key={api_key}&code=12345&keyword={Group Keyword}&message=testMessage](https://api.txtwire.com/httppost?phone=18885554433,18885554422&username=%7Busername%7D&password=%7Bpassword%7D&api_key=%7Bapi_key%7D&code=12345&keyword=%7BGroup%20Keyword%7D&message=testMessage)

My only other option is to user their SOAP web service. which is cumbersome and i would prefer RESTful. would SOAP be better if passing credentials in URL is not preferred? 
Here is the API : https://api.txtwire.com/documentation/class_w_s___message.html#a99faeee5de80610649b184f180098982

will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Is it permitted? Well, this is a question that API service provider should answer. It looks like that textWire API doesn't have any issue with it.

For the sake of security, personally, I don't like to post/get credentials without being encrypted. Even with Basic Authorization, there is a way to add encrypted username and password as request header `"Authorization"`. Something similar to the following:

```
headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic '+ <encoded Base 64 String (username + password)>
```

Perhaps you want to find out if textWire API support such approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should be ok for both of them, from what I can see they're using an SSL+TLS certificate.

From a more technical point of view, passing the password as part of the query string (RESTful), passing it in the request body (SOAP) or passing it as a request header is actually the same approach (don't forget that basic authentication trasmits the credentials as `username:password` sequence encoded with base64), because the password itself is being transmitted along with the message itself.
It's a possibile practice, but I would not raccomend it. If I were to expose an authenticated service I would use a username+HMAC signature combination, or maybe an autentication token of some sort.